# What To Put Inside Laravel Stripe API CreditCardToken

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5

```
I have an error in my code can someone tell me what to put inside the creditcardtoken in stripe? This is my code dont know what to put inside $creditCardToken Variable. 


Route::get('/sandbox', function () {
    $user = new \App\User;
    $user = $user::find(1);
    $user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($creditCardToken);
});
```

The Error Im recieving is this.

Api in RequestOptions.php line 77:
The second argument to Stripe API method calls is an optional per-request apiKey, which must be a string, or per-request options, which must be an array. (HINT: you can set a global apiKey by "Stripe::setApiKey()").

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but have you read the documentation?

Comment: I have read but Im confused can you show example?

Comment: Im a total newbie :(

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#authentication - I assume you need to set it at the beginning of your script

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#handling-other-webhooks there instruction is quite confusing

Comment: I solve it now thanks for replying just realized the the token is dynamically created using the stripe form

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9KKjxEq0Lg found the answer here